# Esri Android Basemap with kml

Tags: kml, arcgis-android

I created a kml using the kmllayer. When I set the map with a basemap and use the addLayer() method the kml is not shown. I can see the kml layer without a basemap. Can someone post sample code on using basemap with kml? am using ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer as basemap

Answer (score 1):

I added a KMLLayer to the HelloWorld sample that comes with the ArcGIS Android SDK.

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
private String url = "http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/us_states.kml";

MapView mMapView = null;
ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer tileLayer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
    mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    /* create a @ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer */
    tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
            "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");

    // Create a new KML Layer
    SpatialReference sr = SpatialReference.create(102100);
    KMLLayer kmlLayer = new KMLLayer(url, sr);

    // Add tiled layer to MapView
    mMapView.addLayer(tileLayer);

    // Add KML Layer to MapView;
    mMapView.addLayer(kmlLayer);

}
```